# Callback before and after a group of test suite in PHPUnit?

Tags: phpunit

Typically when we can define the callback before and/or after the test case. Are there any callback for the test suite using data provider?

(i.e. run before or/and after a group of test cases?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such callback. Also note that all data providers are executed before the first test is executed.